# bash (nano receives SIGHUP or SIGTERM and sudo's password disappears)

Tags: bash, tcp, exec

I'm trying to developing a script that shows if the site `ip.com` is up (background output in `ttttttttt.out`)

```
#!/bin/bash

exec >"ttttttttt.out" 2>>"ttttttttt.out" </dev/null

while true; do
        A=$(timeout 1 bash -c 'exec 3<> /dev/tcp/ip.com/80;echo $?' 2>/dev/null);
        if [[ "$A" == "0" ]];then echo "ip.com connected"; else echo "ip.com unconnected";  fi;
        sleep 1;
done;
```

If it's executed in the background:

```
$ ./ip.com &
```

and I start nano on edkewkn.ewdnjewn (random name)

```
$ pico edkewkn.ewdnjewn
```

after 2-3 seconds I get the error `Received SIGHUP o SIGTERM` and pico quits.

---

I've noticed that if I try to run `sudo kill -9 PID` it's impossible because the prompt disappears like this

```
username@computer:~/dir$ sudo kill -9 5999
[sudo] password for username:
username@computer:~/dir$
```

It does not give me the time to put in the password. I've to exit from the shell and do an other ssh access to have the shell working

---

After some testing I understand that the problem is `bash -c`.

I need to use this script in this way (saving in variable) and I need to use only bash (not netcat or others software, because they don't are available in some shells I have).

Why this? And **how can I modify this line** to make it work?

```
A=$(timeout 1 bash -c 'exec 3<> /dev/tcp/ip.com/80; echo $?' 2>/dev/null);
```

---

Also, if I remove stdin, stdout, stderr and the variable (like here over) the problem persists

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
       #timeout 1 sleep 2             #in this way it works good
       #timeout 1 bash 'sleep 2'      #in this way it works bad

        timeout 1 bash -c 'sleep 2'   #in this way it works bad
        sleep 1;
done;
```

so the error comes directly from `bash`.

PPS I'm over SSH

```
root        1162   0.0  0.5  10008  5604 ?        Ss   Jan03   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root        11288  0.0  0.6  10640  6232 ?        Ss   15:08   0:00  \_ sshd: username [priv]
username    11486  0.0  0.3  10776  3188 ?        S    15:08   0:01  |   \_ sshd: username@pts/3
username    11505  0.1  0.5   7504  5184 pts/3    Ss   15:08   0:03  |       \_ -bash
username    12500  0.0  0.2   5456  2696 pts/3    S    16:10   0:00  |           \_ /bin/bash ./script.sh
username    13776  0.0  0.0   4460   684 pts/3    S    16:10   0:00  |           |   \_ timeout 1 sleep 2
username    13777  0.0  0.0   4280   576 pts/3    S    16:10   0:00  |           |       \_ sleep 2
username    13779  0.0  0.3   7912  3184 pts/3    R+   16:10   0:00  |           \_ ps auxf --sort pid
root        12293  1.0  0.6  10640  6304 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00  \_ sshd: username [priv]
username    12399  0.0  0.3  10772  3196 ?        S    16:10   0:00  |   \_ sshd: username@notty
username    12405  0.0  0.1   2576  1792 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00  |       \_ /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
root        14039  0.0  0.6  10640  6304 ?        Ss   15:09   0:00  \_ sshd: username [priv]
username    14176  0.0  0.3  10784  3192 ?        S    15:09   0:00      \_ sshd: username@notty
username    14215  0.0  0.1   2576  1868 ?        Ss   15:09   0:00          \_ /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server


#@John Bollinger if u can see the light with this could be u're a sensitive :)
  PID  PPID  PGID   SID CMD
19237 19225 19237 19237 -bash
22848 19237 22848 19237 /bin/bash ./script.sh
23512 22848 22848 19237 sleep 2
23563 19237 23563 19237 ps -o pid,ppid,pgid,sid,cmd
```

and before someone asks i'm over an old linux ubuntu version running on an old computer

```
$ uname -a
Linux XXXXXXXX 4.4.0-142-generic #168-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 16 21:01:15 UTC 2019 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
~
$ pico
GNU nano 2.5.3
~
Bash Version: 4.3
Patch Level: 48
Release Status: release
~
$ ulimit -Sa
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 7611
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 7611
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
~
$ ulimit -Ha
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 7611
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1048576
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) unlimited
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 7611
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
~
#think that's not the u limit (from top)
$ top
Tasks: 184 total,   1 running, 183 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
~
$ sudo cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
[sudo] password : 
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog no
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

UseDNS no
GSSAPIAuthentication no
```

Comment: Does it happen with other editors?

Comment: "Does it happen with other editors?" => Hi @konsolebox only with nano. I've noted also that is I try to make `sudo kill -9 PID` it's impossible because the prompt disappears like this `username@computer:~/dir\n$ sudo kill -9 5999\n[sudo] password for username: username@computer:~/dir$` It does not give me the time to put in the password. I've to exit from the shell and do an other ssh access to have the shell working

Comment: Must be nano's inability to update opened files.  It's either a bug or simply a limitation.  Is the file you're trying to open `ttttttttt.out`?

Comment: @konsolebox - "Must be nano's inability to update opened files. It's either a bug or simply a limitation. Is the file you're trying to open ttttttttt.out?" NO. If u read i wrote `$ pico edkewkn.ewdnjewn` It means a file in general. It's a problem that comes from bash -c

Comment: do you get SIGHUP/SIGTERM when `./ip.com` is **not** running?

Comment: @kevinnls "do you get SIGHUP/SIGTERM when ./ip.com is not running?" obviusly NO. I think all but I'm not so stupid :)

Comment: hmmm could you try removing `</dev/null` from the first line of code please?

Comment: @kevinnls "hmmm could you try removing </dev/null from the first line of code please?" PLS @kevinnls i lovvu so much, but leave space to someone who knows the answer and can explain the why. I've done it only to make you fulfilled. THE SAME THING. It's the sdout. Why I shoud remove it?! I said that the problem it's in code line where appares `bash -c`. If i change it it works. Tnkz 4 your kindness to help me, but I think that do attempts without knowing what we're doing it's not a good answer. Waiting 4 expert on this. TNKS guy

Comment: there's a lack of information. and seeing as nobody else has been able to replicate your issue, there's not much that can be done :) and `</dev/null` is input. not output. it might have been the reason for password entry being garbled. from what i can tell, exec has been run in the interactive shell session and fds are garbled. that is the ONLY explanation.

Comment: @kevinnls "there's a lack of information" ?! "and seeing as nobody else has been able to replicate your issue, there's not much that can be done :)" take time, life is long "and </dev/null is input. not output" this is true. I think a thing and I wrote an other "it might have been the reason for password entry being garbled. from what i can tell, exec has been run in the interactive shell session and fds are garbled. that is the ONLY explanation" What can I wrote is that I'm garbled above than your password, then fds and the interactive shell session. Now stay calm and look for a good answer:)

Comment: I do not reproduce the behavior you describe with my versions of bash (4.4.20) and pico (5.09), and I find it hard to believe that it would be associated with the `bash` command rather than with `timeout`.  It is possible that the output of the command `ps -o pid,ppid,pgid,sid,cmd` (while the script is running) would shed some light on the situation.

Comment: You could also try running the script in a separate session via the `setsid` command instead of putting it in the background in the current session: `setsid ./ip.com`. But note that this will probably mean that the script keeps running when you log out, which it should not do the way you are presently launching it.

Comment: @John Bollinger "You could also try running the script in a separate session via the setsid command instead of putting it in the background in the current session: setsid ./ip.com. But note that this will probably mean that the script keeps running when you log out, which it should not do the way you are presently launching it. " ==> I want it over the session I'm using

Comment: @John Bollinger "I do not reproduce the behavior you describe with my versions of bash (4.4.20) and pico (5.09), and I find it hard to believe that it would be associated with the bash command rather than with timeout. It is possible that the output of the command ps -o pid,ppid,pgid,sid,cmd (while the script is running) would shed some light on the situation." ==> Added 4 you the output u required in the quesion

Comment: There is something going on here that has not been captured by the problem description.  I don't think the issue is directly related to `bash`.  It is probably environmental, such as a very low ulimit on the maximum number of concurrent processes you may have on the affected machine, or something unusual in the shell configuration scripts, or something in the sshd configuration.

Comment: John Bollinger "There is something going on here that has not been captured by the problem description. I don't think the issue is directly related to bash. It is probably environmental, such as a very low ulimit on the maximum number of concurrent processes you may have on the affected machine, or something unusual in the shell configuration scripts, or something in the sshd configuration" ==> (added also this) So?

Comment: That was not a request for more information, it was an assertion that we probably cannot troubleshoot this for you.

Comment: John Bollinger "That was not a request for more information, it was an assertion that we probably cannot troubleshoot this for you." you could think in a more constructive way: if someone knows how to adjust this (also asking more informations) i'm here to give it. Tnks the same @John Bollinger. Now give space to the others